# How to adjust page size while publishing?

Tags: octave, tex, export-to-pdf

Software: Octave v7.1.0

- There seems to be no option of defining the page size while doing `publish ("FILE", "pdf")` . The manual for pdf is: 11.11.1 [docs.octave/.../Publish](https://docs.octave.org/v7.1.0/Publish-Octave-Script-Files.html).
- It's kinda surprising as it's a one word addition to the output TeX file : `a4paper`. I can do this manually each time I `publish` but being able to specify it somehow within the `publish` function would be awesome.
- Surprisingly, there are plenty options for specifying page size in figures and images. Search for `papertype` at: 15.3.3.2 [docs.octave/.../Figure-Properties](https://docs.octave.org/v7.1.0/Figure-Properties.html)

- I searched with "Matlab" and found this page, and it fetched the results for "Matlab Report Generator" `mlreportgen` which seems a different thing.
- I'd be interested to listen about other ways of doing it automatically too (like adding that word in TeX file via shell scripting and text string manipulation maybe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As directed by @cris-luengo in the pointer comment to the **linked manual**, one solution can be to edit (or create) the function files (to used by the `publish` function) with the desired changes to specify the paper size.

The function files location can be found by:

- opening the function file in octave gui and then proceeding from there: 
  `edit (fullfile (fileparts (which ("publish")), "private", "__publish_html_output__.m"))`
- or, executing the following in octave REPL/command line: 
  `fullfile (fileparts (which ("publish")), "private")`

There, among other files, 2 files will be:

```
__publish_html_output__.m
__publish_latex_output__.m
```

Edit the `_latex_` containing file to add `,a4paper` (or other predefined size in latex) alongwith `10pt` in the line `'\documentclass[10pt]{article}',`, optionally with a comment in a proceeding newline as a reminder that you added it, something like: `'% Modification: specify a4paper',`

If pdf format were directly specified as a new function file, then I'd have preferred to modify its copy and calling that directly in `publish()`, but since the publish pdf eventually calls publish latex, so, the only option at hand in this method seems to edit the original publish latex function file itself.